# libx265-36 install error

Tags: software-installation

```
l@ubuntu:/opt$ sudo apt-get install libx265-36
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-freefont-otf
  fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot
  fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-inconsolata
  fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-lobster
  fonts-lobstertwo fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-sil-gentium
  fonts-sil-gentium-basic linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic texlive-fonts-extra-doc
  ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libx265-36
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/455 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,224 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 335140 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libx265-36_1.4~20141102~trusty~ppa1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx265-36:amd64 (1.4~20141102~trusty~ppa1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-36_1.4~20141102~trusty~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so', which is also in package libx265-32:amd64 1.3~20140923~trusty~ppa1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-36_1.4~20141102~trusty~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the libx265-32 and then install the libx265-36.

The libx265-36 has conflicts&replaces for the libx265-34.

```
:~$ apt-cache show libx265-36
Package: libx265-36
Source: x265
Priority: extra
Section: libs
...
Replaces: libx265-34
Conflicts: libx265-34
...
Filename: pool/main/x/x265/libx265-36_1.4~20141102~trusty~ppa1_amd64.deb
```

That means if you are upgrading from the libx265-34 to the libx265-36 then the upgrade will go without hickups.

At here:

```
Log of sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Sun Nov  2 23:02:43 2014

...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libx265-34
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libx265-36
...
```

**----EDIT----**

There is a new version 1.4~20141102~trusty~ppa2. It has replaces&conflicts the libx265-30, libx265-31, libx265-32, libx265-33, libx265-34.